# Set UIAlertView delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertview

I try to have the delegate method called but it isn't. What should I change in my code? Thank you.

I tried to add in Class1.m:

```
+(void)popupAlert:(NSString*)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag{
       Class1 *c= [[Class1 alloc]init];
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:c (I also tried c.self)
                                              cancelButtonTitle:...
                                              otherButtonTitles:...,nil];
        alert.tag=tag;
        [alert show];
    }
```

I try to set alertview delegate to make this delegate method called.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Here is what I'm doing:
Class1.h:

```
+(void)popupAlert:(NSString*)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag;
```

Class1.m:

```
+(void)popupAlert:(NSString*)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:...
                                          otherButtonTitles:...,nil];
    alert.tag=tag;
    [alert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
//some coding
}
```

Class2.m:

```
-(void)func1{
[Class1 popupAlert:@"blah blah" tag:0];
}
```

Comment: There are so many problems and bad errors in your code. You should consider to read beginner books about iOS development and Objective-C.

Comment: Change the `+` methods to `-` methods. Class2 should have a Class1 object (as a property) that will call the methods for it.

Comment: @dasdom I will. but can you specify what are the problems and errors? So I can go more deeper about them. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Names. Objective-C is very verbose. 2. Memory management and scope. c will be gone when `popupAlert` returns. 3. Difference between class methods and instance methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alertview delegate property is week reference.

So once you finished the +(void)popupAlert:(NSString*)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag method then all local variables **on Stack** will removed from memory.

means destroyed. So even you set the delegate there it wont work.

```
  @property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;
```

So you should do like this

```
-(void)func1{

    Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];

    [Class1 popupAlert:@"blah blah" tag:0 withDelegate:class1];
}



+(void)popupAlert:(NSString*)msg tag:(NSInteger)tag withDelegate:(id)delegateOfAlert]{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:delegateOfAlert
                                          cancelButtonTitle:...
                                          otherButtonTitles:...,nil];
    alert.tag=tag;
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems c gets dealloced right after [alert show]; because there are no strong reference pointing to this object afterwards and the delegate becomes nil;

In other example you should turn instance method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

to class method:

```
+(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: But I have instance methods in delegate method. I can't do what you'r saying :/ I'm reading all answers right now. Then I will look how I can change my code.

Comment: I marked Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot's answer but both of you similar for  that subject. Thank you, i upvote your answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Rethink your architecture.

You are creating the alert in a class method. (That is indicated by the leading `+` instead of `-`). Within that `self` is a reference to the class, not the object.

`alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is an instance method. I am not even sure that you could apply a delegate protocol to the class instead of the instances. But if you can, then your delegate method would have to be a class method too.

```
+(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Well, I am just thinking of that and DO NOT PROMISE that it works that way. 
If I were you I'd go for a singleton pattern and use instance methods to throw the alert and to respond to the delegate protocol.

Anyway, I am wondering which warning xcode displays on delegate:self and why you are not telling us about the warning. Warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Actually at the beginning, I created UIAlertViews in Class1 but Class1 was very long. So I tried to split the Class1 into some classes. For example: CreatingAlert, ControllingTextFields,.. etc. The question that I asked was about CreatingAlert. I decide to create alerts in Class2 and than I create them in Class1 view controller. Is it wrong to split a class like that to be more efficient or is it just look like efficient but it only makes code more complicated?

Comment: It is not generally wrong splitting a class, but not only for the reason that it is long. You may find other helper methods that you could split off more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will search about it.